# TPL parallelism degree heuristic

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

`Parallel.ForEach` works over `ThreadPool` and by default TPL set the number of threads so it achieves the most performance based on some internal rules. But does .NET take into account parallel or nested `Parallel.Foreach` calls?
For example let assume .NET decided that for current environment **10** threads is the best choice and we have:

```
Parallel.ForEach(collection1, (o1) => {Parallel.ForEach(collection2, (o2) => {...}})
```

Will it produce **10*10** threads?

---

The [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/is-it-ok-to-use-nested-parallel-for-loops/) I've found now make me think that "internal rules" of thread scheduling are so advanced and dynamic, that it can rationally handle described cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not produce threads but tasks. The two loops will [indirectly cooperate](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/is-it-ok-to-use-nested-parallel-for-loops/). This cooperation is not perfect and might lead to more tasks queued than necessary/optimal. Each loop keeps one replica queued to the scheduler. This allows for the scheduler to start more tasks than optimal.

In any case this does not mean that 100 threads are competing for OS resources. The threadpool is made to deal with oversubscription. It tends to produce more threads than there are CPUs, though, to be able to deal with blocking.

Try to avoid nested loops. Usually, it is best to have only one parallel loop at a time. You could, for example, do this:

```
var items =
 from o1 in collection1
 from o2 in collection2
 select new { o1, o2 };

Parallel.ForEach(items, ...);
```

If your architecture requires nested loops you can have them.

Comment: Not every situation allows such merge. And why do you think 100 is quantity of tasks not threads? Imho threadpool is the key point here and tasks number can be much more. And [about nested loops](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/14/10283025.aspx)

Comment: Not threads because the parallel loops do not deal in terms of threads. They do not start any.; That link is interesting. It invalidates part of my answer. But not the conclusion: It is ok to have those loops although not optimal. The thread pool might start more "replica" than is optimal.

Comment: They are not 1:1. The pool queues tasks and dispatches them onto a smaller number of threads. The number of threads is chosen by a heuristic.

Comment: Ok, I didn't fully understand the article. Maybe there is two heuristic for tasks and thread pool.

Comment: There isn't really a heuristic for tasks in the loop. The loop queues new tasks until the scheduler is saturated. The scheduler is normally a threadpool scheduler. The threadpool has a heuristic for the number of threads.